# Variable CATEGORIAS no existe al a hacer FOREACH con Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Dispongo de:
VIEW:

- insertarPregunta.blade.php

CONTROLADOR:

- CategoriaController.php

Al tratar de hacer un FOREACH en la VIEW de la función index() del controlador, me devulve variable "$categorias" no definida. ¿Qué sucede?

ERROR:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: categorias (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/euskaraz/resources/views/insertarPregunta.blade.php)
```

Código del FOREACH en la VIEW insertarPregunta.php

```
@foreach($categorias as $categoria)
  {{$categoria->nombre}}
@endforeach
```

CategoriaController.php donde quiero que la lista de categorias vaya a la VIEW insertarPregunta:

```
class CategoriaController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $categorias=Categoria::all();
        return view("insertarPregunta", compact("categorias"));
    }
```

¿O debería hacerlo en el controlador PreguntaController.php?

Rutas creadas:

```
Route::resource('/preguntas','PreguntaController');
Route::resource('/categorias','CategoriaController');
```

Para probar dd($categorias) creo una ruta provisional:

```
Route::get('/prueba','CategoriaController@index');
```

Y muestra un array con todos los datos que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de PreguntaController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Pregunta;
use App\Categoria;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class PreguntaController extends Controller
{

 public function index()
    {
    $categorias=Categoria::all();
    return view("insertarPregunta", compact("categorias"));
    }


 public function create()
    {
        //
    }


 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $pregunta=new Pregunta;
        $pregunta->categoria=$request->categoria;
        $pregunta->pregunta=$request->pregunta;
        $pregunta->respuesta1=$request->respuesta1;
        $pregunta->respuesta2=$request->respuesta2;
        $pregunta->respuesta3=$request->respuesta3;
        $pregunta->respuesta4=$request->respuesta4;
        $pregunta->save();
    }


 public function show(Pregunta $pregunta)
    {

    }


 public function edit(Pregunta $pregunta)
    {
        //
    }


 public function update(Request $request, Pregunta $pregunta)
    {
        //
    }


 public function destroy(Pregunta $pregunta)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Estas invocando en el controlador el namespace de Cv Categorías ?

Comment: Por cierto pudieras por favor agregar tu código como texto en lugar de imagen?

Comment: Órale, está muy raro tu error, ¿qué te imprime si haces un `dd($categorias);` antes de ejecutar `view();` en tu controlador?

Comment: El la view(insertarPregunta) hay un formulario donde quiero mostrar un select de las categorias. por eso quiero que el controlador CategoriaController envie la lista de categorias para en la VIEW hacer un foreach. ¿Qué es "CvCategorias"?

Comment: @alderson Sí, si entendí, pero, ¿podrías mencionar lo que te imprime lo siguiente en tu controlador: `dd($categorias);` antes de mandar a llamar a tu vista.

Comment: para probar dd($categorias) creo una ruta provisional Route::get('/prueba','CategoriaController@index'); y me devuelve un array con los datos que necesito.

Comment: Si entras a /categorias desde el navegador, si debería funcionar. Ahora si entras a /preguntas no. Entonces deberías agregar el código del index de categorías al index del controlador de preguntas para que la ruta /preguntas funcione.

Comment: Así es Bryan. /categorias funciona /preguntas no funciona. ¿Cómo hay que hacer para agrager el código index de categorias al indes del controlador de preguntas? Gracias.

Comment: el codigo que esta dentro del metodo index del CategoriaController, copialo y pegalo dentro del metodo index del PreguntaController

Comment: Que el método index del preguntaController quede igual que el index del CategoriaController

Comment: Así lo he hecho, sigue dando el mismo error: "Undefined variable: categorias (View: ...resources/views/insertarPregunta.blade.php)". ¿Cómo se supone que tiene o le llega a la vista insertarPregunta.blade.php el array $categorias?

Comment: En tu PreguntaController, estas usando el modelo Categoria? especificamente: use App\Categoria; ?

Comment: No lo tenía añadido use App\Categoria. Lo he añadido pero sigue dando el mismo error Bryan.

Comment: El método view es el que recibe la vista y los datos (a parte de otros datos), el método compact es el encargado de buscar y crear/unir variables(nombres y valores)

Comment: Agrego por favor el codigo del controlador PreguntaController

Comment: No creo que sea, pero solo para probar. Si tienes andando el server de laravel, detenlo y vuelve a correrlo y prueba. Antes debió mostrarte 2 errores diferentes, solo por eso.

Comment: Ya he añadido el código de PreguntaController.php a ver si aparece lo que hago mal.

Comment: Está correcto. Ahora, comenta todo el código dentro del método index del PreguntaController y escribe dd('Test PreguntaController'); y accede a /preguntas desde el navegador

Comment: De alguna menera tenemos que cambiar el comportamiento

Comment: Al hacer ese cambio, el navegador (haciendo: ...public/preguntas) muestra el texto: "Test PreguntaController"

Comment: perfecto, descomenta la linea $categorias y escribe dd($categorias);

Comment: De esa manera el navegador muestra el array con toda la información necesaria.

Comment: comenta el dd y descomenta el return view. Con esto solo estamos haciendo el flujo desde el comienzo para comprobar que no tengamos un error hasta este punto. y vuelve a cargar la misma url (/preguntas)

Comment: ¡Vaya! ¡Ahora se ve perfecto en /preguntas. No comprendo qué hemos cambiado para que ahora se vea y antes no. Con la ruta /preguntas se ve bien. Con la ruta /insertarPregunta da error. ¿Utilizo la ruta /preguntas y ya está?

Comment: jajajaja no lo digas en voz alta que te van a matar jaja. claro, cuando creas un controlador de tipo resource, el index es la url que le asignas desde el routes.php, o desde ahi siguen los demas metodos ejemplo: preguntas => metodo index, preguntas/create => metodo create, preguntas/edit => metodo edit

Comment: En la documentacion de laravel aparece bien detallado cada tipo de rutas y controladores por si quieres estar mas claro con este tema. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers. Me alegra que lo solucionaras

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Bryan Retamal! ; )

Answer (score 0):

prueba hacer el `return` del controlador asi:

```
 $categorias=Categoria::all();
 return view('insertarPregunta')->with('categorias',$categorias);
```